# Given a φ independent of PA which is true in the standard model, will always (PA+ ¬φ) be Σn-unsound for some n?

Tags: logic, arithmetic, incompleteness

Given a φ independent of PA which is true in the standard model, will always (PA+ ¬φ) be Σn-unsound for some n?
This is a follow up from a previous question:
[Given a φ independent of PA which is true in the standard model, will always (PA+ ¬φ) be ω-inconsistent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226956/given-a-independent-of-pa-which-is-true-in-the-standard-model-will-always-pa).

Comment: Isn't this tautological? $\lnot\varphi$ is false, and provable in PA$+\lnot\varphi$. But $\lnot\varphi$ is (equivalent to) a $\Sigma_n$ formula for some $n$.

Comment: I see your point, but what if ¬φ is equivalent to a PIn formula? (I might be asking something obvious, I apologize if that is the case, I am just a physicist)

Comment: A $\Pi^0_n$ formula is also $\Sigma^0_{k}$ for every $k > n$ (and $\Pi^0_k$ and $\Delta^0_k$). So every formula is $\Sigma^0_n$ for infinitely many $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Every formula "is" $\Sigma^0_n$ for sufficiently large $n$, and the rest follows directly from the definition of a theory being $\Sigma^0_n$ unsound.

There are two ways to read the above statement. Some people would define the arithmetical hierarchy so that each formula has infinitely many rankings. But even if we only give a formula its lowest ranking, every formula $\phi$ will be logically equivalent to a formula $\psi$ that is $\Sigma^0_n$ for some $n$; just add dummy quantifiers to the prenex form of $\phi$ until it starts with an existential quantifier. Then any theory that proves $\phi$ also proves $\psi$. This is why, for most purposes, we can look at the arithmetical hierarchy "modulo logical equivalence" or even modulo provable equivalence in our theory.

Comment: I wrote an answer just so there was something to accept; I marked it "community wiki" so there is no reputation associated with it.